# How to remove inner child object by specific Id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my json structure:

```
$scope.dataList = [{
   CompanyName: null,
   Location: null,
   Client: [{
      ClientId: 0,
      ClientName: null,
      Projects:{
         Id: 0,
         Name: null,
      }
   }]
}];
```

I am trying to `remove client data by` `specific clientid from list of clients` but client data is not getting removed and i am not getting any kind of error.

**Code:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dataList.length; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.dataList[i].Client.length; j++)
                {
                    if ($scope.dataList[i].Client[j].ClientId == 101)
                    {
                       $scope.dataList[i].Client.splice(j, 1);
                    }     
                }
            }
```

Can anybody tell me what is the problem with my code??

Comment: are you sure that you execute `$scope.dataList[i].Client.splice(j, 1);` maybe never enter in the if condition

Comment: @gianlucatursi Awesome catch.Yeah that was the problem.Thanks.Just 1 question that is it possible to do this removal without loop??

Comment: I do not think. You can use `underscore` for having a better code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use delete statement for this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dataList.length; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.dataList[i].Client.length; j++)
                {
                    if ($scope.dataList[i].Client[j].ClientId == 101)
                    {
                       delete $scope.dataList[i].Client[j];
                    }     
                }
            }
```

But this will be create problem when you are delete because in for loop one item delete so item count decrease.

So you have to use other way for this.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dataList.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < $scope.dataList[i].Client.length; j++) {
    var foundIndex;
    if ($scope.dataList[i].Client[j].ClientId == 101){
      foundIndex = j;
    }
    $scope.dataList[i].Client.splice(j, 1);
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uv3zo0y2/

Comment: Is this possible to do this without for loop and instead used some inbuilt function to do this???

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But you can use libraries like lodash or underscore to make the code more readable, by using "each" and "filter"-functions.